# Fractional RotateRight

Tags: list-manipulation

I want a way to rotate a list to the right by a fractional amount, i.e. I want a function `fractionalRotateRight[data, 2.3]` that would rotate data two positions to the right, and then an extra 0.3 positions.

Comment: What does it mean by "0.3 positions"?

Comment: I imagine that the list is the values of a periodic function sampled evenly. When I 'shift' by 0.3 positions I want to estimate from the current sample, what the sample would have been, had I shifted my sampling positions by 0.3 units. That's how I think about it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
  fractionalRotateRight[data_, shift_] := Module[{n, f, nShift},
      n = IntegerPart[shift];
      f = FractionalPart[shift];
      nShift = RotateRight[data, n];
      If[shift >= 0,
         MovingAverage[Prepend[nShift, nShift[[-1]]], {f, 1 - f}],
         MovingAverage[Append[nShift, nShift[[1]]], {1 - Abs[f], Abs[f]}]
      ]
  ]
```

Example (1): The input `fractionalRotateRight[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 1.7]` produces the output `{0., 0., 0., 0.3, 0.7}`

Example (2): The input `fractionalRotateRight[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, -1.7]` produces the output `{0.7, 0.3, 0., 0., 0.}`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use interpolation.

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10]
int = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
shift = 0.2; 
int[# + shift] & /@ Range[10] // Quiet
```

list is the list that you want to rotate, shift is the amount to rotate. int[x] is a function that you can index into at will, in particular at all the shifted locations. The Quiet is needed because at the ends you are extrapolating, and this generates a warning (but not an error).